# Angularjs get data filtered in ng-repeat from controller

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have tried everything but I can't get it.

What i need is to access data filtered in ng-repeat from controller.

Data in ng-repeat is taken from a $http call.

```
$http.get('http://localhost:/test/test.php').success(function(data) {

 $scope.registros = data;

 });
```

and this is the view

```
<div ng-repeat="registro in (filteredregistros = (registros| filter:userSearch | filter:datefilter | filter:greaterThan('ID', greatersearch) |  orderBy:'-ID'))">


             {{registro.ID}}{{registro.date}}

             <div class="rowboxdata ng-animate">

                                        <div class=""><div class="name-business">{{registro.Name}}</div></div>
                                        <div class=""><div class="name-business">{{registro.Phone}}</div></div>
                                        <div class=""><div class="name-business">{{registro.Email}}</div></div>
                                        <div class=""><div class="name-business">{{registro.Name}}</div></div>
                                        <div class=""><div class="name-business">{{registro.City}}</div></div>
                                        <div class=""><div class="name-business">{{registro.Service}}</div></div>
             </div>

</div>
```

I have tried access data filtered from my controller with $scope.filteredregistros as i look in other post, but it didn't work to me.

What I'm trying to do, is to get data filtered and then, send it through ajax to php.

Would be nice some help thanks.

**EDITED**

Finally, I have found what I needed with this example;

In the View:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="results(filteredregistros)" />
```

In the Controller:

```
$scope.results = function (filteredregistros) {
          console.log(filteredregistros);
          // your ajax code
};
```

And if you want to get it only in the view, then do it as Per Hornshøj-Schierbeck says:

```
filteredregistros: {{filteredregistros | json}}
```

Thanks for the help Per Hornshøj-Schierbeck

Comment: Can you provide me sample json?

Comment: Show the example where you try to read your filteredregistros. Remember that data won't be accessible untill your http request completes and the filter code run...

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck well all i tried was var test1 = $scope.filteredregistros;  console.log(test1)

Comment: @PareshGami the sample json result is here, in a comment in the reply from per hornshoj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
filteredregistros: {{filteredregistros | json}}
```

in your HTML somewhere. It should be clear if it contains data or not. Piping it through `json` will display the data in json format, which is nice for debugging the value inside.

The reason why you might not see if, when you do `console.log` is, that depending on when you `console.log` it, your http request might or might not have run and the data might not be filtered yet.

Comment: What are your registros values then? You can debug them either in the HTML or just console.log the data in your success method on the $http.get call

Comment: I forgot to change in my php mysql_fetch_array to mysql_fetch_object thats why it returned numbers and properties instead of properties

Comment: So did it solve your problem or what is the problem now?

Comment: Finally !! it was something stupid but.. this worked. In the click button ng-click="select(filteredregistros)" and then in the controller  $scope.select = function (filteredregistros) {
              console.log(filteredregistros);
        }; and this returned me the objects i filtered and only the results. Thanks for your help @Per Hornshøj-Schierbeck